# OpenPGP encryption of mails in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, email, encryption

I've been trying to find out any way to OpenPGP encrypt mails while sending from Apple Mail or any other email app in Mountain Lion.

GPGTools' GPGMail is not yet ready for Mountain Lion.

MailMate application depends on gpg2 command & GPGTool's GPGKeyChain Access but when I tried by installing the required softwares, MailMate gave me some error when I tried to send. It seems the feature is not yet stable.

Am I missing anything else ?

Answer (score 3):

> GPGTools' GPGMail is not yet ready for Mountain Lion.

[It is now](https://gpgtools.org/). It seems like they have speed up their development and are now working on 10.9 (Mavericks) support.

Answer (score 0):

[Mailsmith](http://www.mailsmith.org/) works fine on Mountain Lion and can use GPG through a [set of AppleScripts](http://alex.primafila.net/Mailsmith-GPG/). Works for me.